# Decrease the time for which the 'thing' appears while switching workspaces: Gnome Shell

Tags: gnome, workspaces

I am using Gnome Shell. I want to decrease the time for which this picture or whatever, telling me, in what workspace I am moving, appears when switching workspaces. Image attached.
[image]

In Unity, it is sufficiently shortlived. But in Shell it remains for a fraction of second longer which really irritates me. When I am reading some Programming stuff on a browser in one workspace and am trying it in an IDE in another, I like to to quickly switch workspaces. I rapidly keep on switching them: reading here and trying there. But that stupid apparition comes in the way for too long.

Answer (score 0):

Open up the `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/workspaceSwitcherPopup.js` file, and find these lines:

```
const ANIMATION_TIME = 0.1;
const DISPLAY_TIMEOUT = 600;
```

Just simply edit these, and Voilá! The first one sets the length of the transition animation (in seconds I guess), the second one the actual display time of the switcher (in milliseconds). Don't forget to restart the Shell after saving the file.